# How to reset PTS for Stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying reset pts on input stream and create new pts and publish stream to RTMP.

```
ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i "movie=${SOURCE}:s=0+1[out0][out1];[0:v]setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB),[0:a]asetpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)" \
       -r 24 -crf 20 \
       -c:v libx264 \
       -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 \
       -f flv ${DEST}
```

If I remove the setpts and asetpts filters them command works. But I need to setpts and asetpts at source before it is given to encoder.

Please help.

Comment: Apply it as regular filters.

Comment: Appreciate example.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the PTS outside the source graph.

```
ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i "movie=${SOURCE}:s=0+1" \
   -vf setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -af asetpts=N/SR/TB
   -r 24 -crf 20 \
   -c:v libx264 \
   -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 \
   -f flv ${DEST}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had to modify the input as per my original command.